# Switching keyboard/mouse/ethernet between two computers

Tags: keyboard, mouse, internet, switch

At work, there are two computers side by side that share the same mouse/keyboard/internet cable (luckily the monitor has two cable inputs). We have to keep on switching these wires whenever we want to use a different computer.

I was wondering if I could make a switching board (or buy one) so that I could have all of these three things plugged in, and I just change a switch instead of all of those cables?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Well, a KVM switch will allow you to easily move between PCs with one Keyboard/Mouse/Monitor, but I've never heard of anything like that for ethernet. You'd be better off buying a KVM and like a cheap 4 port switch and using that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called a KVM switch. It doesnt do ethernet though.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look into Synergy:
http://synergy-foss.org/

I've never used this, but it's freeware and I've heard wonderful things about it.

But, beyond that, wouldn't it just be easier to get another keyboard/mouse/Ethernet cable set for the other computer? o_o.

Comment: Synergy is not freeware anymore.