# How to work on Two different OS on two different machines simultaneously

Tags: macos, operating-systems, computer-building, multitasking

So, I have a Windows Laptop - Dell XPS 15 (L502X) and a lot of time I have to work on Linux environment. But the thing is that On Linux i have to have some virtual environments running with Vagrant and Virtualbox.
Now, I can't run a Virtual Linux environment under my Windows OS and then have another Virtual environment under the Virtual Linux environment. 
The only choice i have is to -

1. Either remove the Windows OS from my Dell Laptop, but when i tried doing so, the machine went unstable and the drivers were not working. The fan was always running at full speed and my laptop became very hot.
2. Now, the only solution is that i have to buy a new computer and then install Ubuntu on it.

The problem however is that I want to have just one desk for both of the systems.

I want to be able to work with just one KEYBOARD and one MOUSE and i want to be able to switch between systems on two different machines whenever i want.

Is there any way i can do that. Because having two KEYBOARDS and MOUSE on a single desk looks weird and there isn't any space to put them either. Also, if  i have two keyboards and mouse i either have to move myself or move the keyboards and mouse whenever i want to switch machines.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I share my usb keyboard between two computers](http://superuser.com/questions/395252/can-i-share-my-usb-keyboard-between-two-computers), [Sharing keyboard and mouse between two boxes](http://superuser.com/questions/770518/sharing-keyboard-and-mouse-between-two-boxes?rq=1), [Switching keyboard/mouse/ethernet between two computers](http://superuser.com/questions/360680/switching-keyboard-mouse-ethernet-between-two-computers?rq=1)...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a KVM switch to have one mouse and keyboard connected to 2 machines.

[Wikipedia - KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch)

You can find KVM switches through any retailer.  Some of the lower end/priced ones tend to have problems waking up machines from sleep, so I would go with a reputable brand.